WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Environment Variable Auto-Creating in Azure App Service Environment
I have a solution containing an Web App and Web Job project, that I build and deploy with Azure DevOps pipelines, which I deploy to an Azure Windows App Service, using the ZipDeploy option. I can deploy the Web App to my DEV and TEST environments with no problem using my Release Pipeline. When I use the same Release Pipeline to Deploy to my PROD environment, the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 environment variable mysteriously appears as an Environment Variable. This setting is NOT in my appsettings.json file, or even my User Secrets file. I have compared the 3 Stages of the Release Pipeline and see no differences (other than the environment Subscription and the App Service name).
I have a second similar solution, with a Web App and 2 Web Jobs projects, which Deploys correctly across all 3 environments. I have compared the Build and Release Pipelines from these 2 DevOps projects and can see no differences.
I can use Kudu to view the appsettings.json files in the App Service file system, and there is no WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE entry in them. Kudu also shows WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 and APPSETTING_WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 in the Environment page -> Environment Variables section. Also, I will swear that I manually deleted the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 environment variable from the App Service Portal, only to have it reappear some time later, which makes no sense at all.
Where could this Environment Variable be coming from?
Addendum:  Out of frustration I again manually deleted the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 from the PROD Environment Variables using the App Service Portal.  After the Web App re-started, it threw an error from the previous build!!!  After manually re-deploying the latest build of the Web App to the PROD environment / Stage using my Azure Release Pipeline, the Web App started working again, and the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1  again magically appeared in the Environment Variables (sigh).
EDIT:  The YAML for the "Azure App Service deploy" Task in the PROD Stage of the Release Pipeline is:
trigger:
  - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
  - stage: BuildStage 
    displayName: Build
    jobs:
    - job:
      displayName: Build 
      steps:
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'build'
            projects: '**/*.csproj'
            arguments: '--configuration Release'
          displayName: 'build'
     
        - script: cp -v mySolution.UI/appsettings.json $(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
          displayName: 'Copy appsettings.json to artifacts folder'
       
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
           command: 'publish'
           publishWebProjects: false
           projects: '**/mySolution.WebJobs.csproj'
           arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/triggered/myWebJob  -r win-x64 --self-contained false'
           zipAfterPublish: false
           modifyOutputPath: false
          displayName: 'Publish myWebJob'

        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'publish'
            publishWebProjects: true
            arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
            zipAfterPublish: false
            modifyOutputPath: false
          displayName: 'Publish Web App'

        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
             rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
             includeRootFolder: false
             archiveType: 'zip'
             archiveFile: '$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
             replaceExistingArchive: true
          displayName: 'Archive Files'
          
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'



Could you confirm if the deployment to your PROD environment uses the same .zip package as DEV and TEST?

If there are differences in the deployment artifacts, that might be triggering the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE variable to appear

if possible can you share your .yml file

please indicate if you're deploying to windows or linux, the app service plan type, which deployment task you're using in your pipeline and the settings provided.

The PROD environment is a Stage in the same Release Pipeline as the DEV and TEST environments, so I assume that the same Zip package and artifacts are being deployed.  Also, the target is a Windows App Service.  Full YAML for the "Azure App Service deploy" Task and PROD Stage was added to my post.

The WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 environment variable is automatically set by Azure App Service when you deploy your application using ZipDeploy. This configuration instructs the Azure App Service to run your application directly from the .zip file package that is uploaded during deployment.
The behavior you're observing is expected and occurs because:

ZipDeploy inherently uses WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 to enable running the app from the package.
Manually removing WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 can cause errors, as the App Service relies on this configuration to locate and execute the deployed package.

The following could explain why you're experiencing this behavior only in PROD:

Different Deployment Settings:

The ZipDeploy method is used explicitly or configured in your PROD pipeline, even if unintentionally.
Compare the deployment tasks in your pipelines (e.g., deployment YAML or GUI settings). If the pipeline uses a Deploy Azure App Service task, check if deployment method is set to ZipDeploy.

App Service Slot Behavior:

For PROD, you might have deployment slots (e.g., staging -> production) that automatically enable WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE.

App Configuration Reset:

During deployment, App Service might re-apply settings required for ZipDeploy, such as WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, overriding manual changes.
If you don't want to use WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, switch to a deployment method that doesn't rely on it, such as Run-From-Folder.

Modify the deployment pipeline to use the RunFromFolder approach:

Unset the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE environment variable in your pipeline.
Configure the deployment task to extract the .zip file on the App Service.

Update the release pipeline task:

task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
inputs:
package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/yourpackage.zip'
deploymentMethod: 'runFromFolder'




I am confused by your statement that "The WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 environment variable is automatically set by Azure App Service when you deploy your application using ZipDeploy" because I have 5 Web Apps being "Zip Deployed" using Release Pipelines to 3 Stages / Environments each.  Only this one "problem" deployment (1 out of 15) is somehow getting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1  auto-added to the Environment Variables; that variable was not added and does not exist in the other 14 deployments yet everything there is running correctly.  Can you refer me to any documentation on this?
